# How to find duplicates of a number in excel?

Tags: excel-2010, vlookup

I have 2 columns of account numbers. The first column has far more numbers than the second column. I need to know if the numbers in column 1 show up anywhere in column two.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,B:B,1,0)
```

in a third column, copied down to all rows populated in ColumnA.